# What is this metal plate below the door?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification

What is this metal plate for?

[image: aircraft door]
([source](http://fr.freeimages.com/premium/aircraft-door-933182))

You can also see it here:

[image: aircraft]
([source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/martinmontingelli/3376670289))

Is found on many aircraft so what is that piece of metal right there?

Comment: The entire hull is metal. Though I would guess for aiming the stairs

Comment: Or a strengthened area to avoid damage to the fuselage due to stairs moving around.

Comment: And/or an access panel to get to the inner workings of the door?

Comment: Greg is right. You can see from the damaged paint below the door on the first image that this area gets more abuse than the rest. It needs some protection. There is more on the inside, because the corners of the door cutout accumulate stress when the fuselage is pressurized. That is also the reason for the massive door locks - most of the stress is transferred into the door.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Greg is correct. It is a scuff plate, to protect the fuselage from damage due to GSE (like jetbridge etc). The image below shows it.

[image: Scuff plate]

Image from [slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/BPancho/13-master-configuration-deviation-list-a320)

The image below shows an example made out of Ti from a manufacturer's site.

[image: scuff plate]

Image from [exoticmetals.com](http://www.exoticmetals.com/products/aircraftstructuralcomponents/)